# Making Textbox accept other languages in .net windows application using c#

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I have started developing an bilingual windows application in Tamil and English. The problem is i want to type Tamil language into text box, I even changed the font of the text box to Tamil but it displays only empty boxes. I just want to know the method for making the text box accept Tamil font. How to do it for .net windows application.

Comment: Did you try changing at runtime culture used in your app?

Comment: No Pls guide me on how to use it..

Answer (score 1):

You could try to change at runtime culture used in your app:

```
using System.Threading;
using System.Globalization;
// Sets the culture to Tamil (India)
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("ta-IN");
// Sets the UI culture to Tamil (India)
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("ta-IN");
```

or (according to this [Microsoft page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.inputlanguage%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)) you can set

```
InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage
```

Comment: Thanks, But i have done this already and even though its not accepting the font in Tamil.

Comment: @user1588242: sorry, I cannot help you more. This is the only idea I had... very sorry.

Comment: Hello thank you for the help provided pls inform me if you get any more details on it..

Answer (score -1):

Try to use RichTextBox control

Comment: I've used it too but it displays all that i typed in English itself.